# What is the simplest way to run sbt re-start before sbt it:test and sbt re-stop afterwards?

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-revolver

I need to do the following in sequential order.

1. Start spray-can server (sbt re-start).
2. Run integration tests (sbt it:test).
3. Stop spray-can server (sbt re-stop).

Can't make it work with sbt-sequential plugin since Revolver.reStart is not a Task.

Comment: What is `re-start`?  A command? A SBT task?

Comment: Add to build.sbt: addCommandAlias("re", "; re-start; it:test; re-stop") then run as "sbt re". No need for additional plugins.